# Refactoring a small Scala function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, refactoring

I have this function to compute the distance between two n-dimensional points using Pythagoras' theorem.

```
def computeDistance(neighbour: Point) = math.sqrt(coordinates.zip(neighbour.coordinates).map {
    case (c1: Int, c2: Int) => math.pow(c1 - c2, 2)
}.sum)
```

The `Point` class (simplified) looks like:

```
class Point(val coordinates: List[Int])
```

I'm struggling to refactor the method so it's a little easier to read, can anybody help please?

Comment: I think it's not worth it. You could create `implicit class`es and implement `map` and `flatMap` in your `Point` class but, in my opinion, it's too much work for too little gain. Now it's clean implementation of mathematical equation.

Comment: Your formula for [N-dimensional Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#N_dimensions) is wrong. See @penland365's answer (or that link) for the correct formula.

Comment: I agree, I only tested it in two dimensions, which is why I didn't realise. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your problem is that you're trying to do math with really long variable names.  It's almost always painful.  There's a reason why mathematicians use single letters.  And assign temporary variables.

Try this:

```
class Point(val coordinates: List[Int]) { def c = coordinates }
import math._
def d(p: Point) = {
  val delta = for ((a,b) <- (c zip p.c)) yield pow(a-b, dims)
  sqrt(delta.sum)
}
```

Comment: I like the `for` comprehension. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way that makes the following three assumptions:

1. The length of the list is the number of dimensions for the point
2. Each List is correctly ordered, i.e. `List(x, y)` or `List(x, y, z)`.  We do not know how to handle `List(x, z, y)`
3. All lists are of equal length

```scala
def computeDistance(other: Point): Double = sqrt(
  coordinates.zip(other.coordinates)
  .flatMap(i => List(pow(i._2 - i._1, 2)))
  .fold(0.0)(_ + _)
)
```

The obvious disadvantage here is that we don't have any safety around list length.  The quick fix for this is to simply have the function return an `Option[Double]` like so:

```scala
def computeDistance(other: Point): Option[Double] = {
  if(other.coordinates.length != coordinates.length) {
    return None
  }
  return Some(sqrt(coordinates.zip(other.coordinates)
    .flatMap(i => List(pow(i._2 - i._1, 2)))
    .fold(0.0)(_ + _)
   ))
```

I'd be curious if there is a type safe way to ensure equal list length.

***EDIT***

It was politely pointed out to me that `flatMap(x => List(foo(x)))` is equivalent to `map(foo)` , which I forgot to refactor when I was originally playing w/ this.  Slightly cleaner version w/ `Map` instead of `flatMap` :

```scala
def computeDistance(other: Point): Double = sqrt(
  coordinates.zip(other.coordinates)
  .map(i => pow(i._2 - i._1, 2))
  .fold(0.0)(_ + _)
)
```

Comment: I use the \/ class in scalaz to try and handle lists with non-uniform lengths. Take a look: https://github.com/Todd-Davies/NearestNeighbour

Comment: +1 for using the [correct formula for Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#N_dimensions) (the OP got it wrong in his post—you always _square_ the individual deltas no matter the number of dimensions).

Comment: Isn't `.fold(0.0){(z, j) => z + j}` the same as `.sum`? Or `.reduce(_ + _)` if you prefer

Comment: @Paul Your objection is valid, however the fold is preferred because it looks like a big eyed guy staring at a butt: `fold(0.0)(_+_)`

Comment: @sscarduzio, Ah. Must have missed that bit of guidance in the style guide.

Answer (score 0):

Consider type aliases and case classes, like this,

```
type Coord = List[Int]

case class Point(val c: Coord) {
  def distTo(p: Point) = {
    val z = (c zip p.c).par
    val pw = z.aggregate(0.0) ( (a,v) => a + math.pow( v._1-v._2, 2 ), _ + _ )
    math.sqrt(pw)
  }
}
```

so that for any two points, for instance,

```
val p = Point( (1 to 5).toList )
val q = Point( (2 to 6).toList )
```

we have that

```
p distTo q
res: Double = 2.23606797749979
```

Note method `distTo` uses `aggregate` on a parallelised collection of tuples, and combines the partial results by the last argument (summation). For high dimensional points this may prove more efficient than the sequential counterpart.

For simplicity of use, consider also implicit classes, as suggested in a comment above,

```
implicit class RichPoint(val c: Coord) extends AnyVal {
  def distTo(d: Coord) = Point(c) distTo Point(d)
}
```

Hence

```
List(1,2,3,4,5) distTo List(2,3,4,5,6)
res: Double = 2.23606797749979
```